# AngularJS $filter(date) returns wrong format

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I have an `AngularJS` filter, which should return a date in a specifik format. However when I do the following:

```
var input = '2015-08-11T13:00:00';
var format = 'yyyy MMM dd - hh:mm:ss';
return $filter('date')(new Date(input), format);
```

it return date like this `2015 Aug 04 - 01:00:00` rather than this `2015 Aug 04 - 13:00:00` why is this, and is there a solution which would allow for any format to work?

Comment: Try 'HH' instead of 'hh' (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date is your friend.

In particular:

> 'HH': Hour in day, padded (00-23)
>
> 'H': Hour in day (0-23)
>
> 'hh': Hour in AM/PM, padded (01-12)
>
> 'h': Hour in AM/PM, (1-12)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

In order for you this to work in military time, change `hh` to `HH`.

Answer (score 2):

Like you can see on [this page](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date), you need to use `HH` (capital letters) to show 24-hour hours.